# Как удалить точки в конце слов? python

Tags: python, строки

Решаю задачу и столкнулся с такой проблемой: Есть множество строки типа "Я увлекаюсь next.js и python." Мне нужно избавиться от точки В КОНЦЕ слов (строки само собой разной длины и содержания). В голову приходят только регулярные выражения. Можно ли реализовать это проще?

Comment: `'...text...'.rstrip('.')` → `'...text'`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
def func(string):
    while True:
        if string.endswith('.'):
            string = string[0:len(string) - 1]
        else:
            return string
```

Данная функция избавляеться от всех точек, что стоят в конце строки

Comment: скажите пожалуйста, а для чего в вашей функции `while True:` ? и если все таки последний символ сроки `.`? то `return string` не нужен?

Comment: @S. Nick похоже что расчёт на количество точек превышающих 1 ведь в текстах может и 3 точки в конце предложения быть

Comment: @Maxym понятно.

Comment: @S.Nick Всё очень просто, нам нужен вечный цикл для того, чтобы убрать все точки в конце строки. При каждой итерации ми проверяем есть ли точка в конце строки, если есть - удаляем, в противном случае возвращаем новою строку без точек

Answer (score 2):

Через `endswith` проверяем, что последним символом будет точка, а с помощью среза `[:-1]` возвращаем строку без последнего символа:

```
text = "Я увлекаюсь next.js и python."
if text.endswith('.'):
    text = text[:-1]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
"..........Вот это удаляет все точки (одну или многоточие) в начале и конце строки. У вас же нету точек в начале, да?.......".strip('.')
```